# Content type 'application/json' not supported in Spring MVC and jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I'm getting an error (Handler execution resulted in exception: Content type 'application/json' not supported) when trying to receive a post request using Spring MVC.

My Json, just for testing, is pretty simple:

```
{ "test": "abc123" }
```

My pojo class:

```
public class Request {

    String test;

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

}
```

And my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testing", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
private void testing(@RequestBody Request body, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
    System.out.println(body.getTest());
}
```

In my pom.xml, I added:

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I think that something is wrong in json deserialization, but I cannot find it.

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` on `produces`, but a string literal on `consumes`? Why do you have `produces` and `@ResponseBody` when method doesn't produce anything? That may have confused Spring MVC to prevent mapping from working.

Comment: @Andreas, `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` is just a constant to `"application/json"`, so I dont think that this is the problem.
Anyway, I removed `produces` and `@ResponseBody` and I still in the same issue.

Comment: @PedroH why do you need this `consumes` attribute at all? It serves only to make mapping more specific. Remove it and try again.

Comment: @Nikem, thanks, but I removed `consumes` and I'm in the same issue.

Comment: try adding Content-Type as application/json while sending the request, i.e., in your ajax method or in the postman

Comment: I tried with and without the content-type in the request header. But still not working

Comment: Don't mix different versions of jackson component. And be sure you version of jackson you want to use is compatible with the version of Spring MVC you use.

Comment: @PedroH I have reworked my answer. Works for me :)

Comment: Thaks @Nikem, I'll test it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my working example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
  }


  @RequestMapping(value = "/testing", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @ResponseBody
  private void testing(@RequestBody Request body, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
    System.out.println(body.getTest());
  }
}
```

This project has only 1 dependency:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web
```

When I call the url like this:

```
curl -XPOST -v -d '{ "test": "abc123" }' -H "Content-type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/testing
```

I see the correct `abc123` in the logs. If I remove `Content-type` header I get the exception

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException","message":"Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported
```

Answer (score 10):

In my case the problem was an addition to a dto of a property which having a type that was error prone for Jackson, it was of type JsonObject. Jackson was unable to deserialize other objects because of that addition.
**The exception message is completely inaccurate!**

Comment: This was a good clue for me. You need to make sure that 1. your object is Serializable and 2. that all pojo getter/setters are properly implemented

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else looking for this problem, I had to have at least one public variable or a getter on my Pojo class.

Answer (score 2):

Add this *Bean* in your webconfig class

```
@Bean
public ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentViewResolver() {
    ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean contentNegotiationManager = new ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean();
    contentNegotiationManager.addMediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

    MappingJackson2JsonView defaultView = new MappingJackson2JsonView();
    defaultView.setExtractValueFromSingleKeyModel(true);

    ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentViewResolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
    contentViewResolver.setContentNegotiationManager(contentNegotiationManager.getObject());
    contentViewResolver.setViewResolvers(Arrays.<ViewResolver> asList(viewResolver));
    contentViewResolver.setDefaultViews(Arrays.<View> asList(defaultView));
    return contentViewResolver;
}
```

**UPDATE**

The guys from the comments are right, this won't fix your issue but I noticed something.

If I set consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE and in the request I don't specify the content type it will throw an exception then if I set the content type the issue is fixed.

Now, the issue seems to be something with your dependencies.

My pom dependencies:

```
 <properties>
     <springframework.version>4.1.9.RELEASE</springframework.version>
     <springframework.security.oauth.version>2.0.9.RELEASE</springframework.security.oauth.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    ...

</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.security.oauth.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    ...

</dependencies>
```

Comment: I dont think that I need this. I'm not even using jsp files.

Comment: Why would they need this? What does this bean contribute that was missing from their configuration?

Comment: Not working yet.
I have all your dependencies and I'm seding the Content-Type "application/json" on my request header.

Comment: Could you remove the consumes? try to use only the com.fasterxml.jackson.core dependency and comment the others

Comment: i have the same problem, dependency jackson-databind solved my problem

Answer (score -1):

For those who use **Spring Framework**, **not** Spring Boot, and encounter this problem.

The **root** of this problem is:

- Spring need to ① **recognize** the "Content-Type", and ② **convert
  the content** to the **parameter type** we declared in the method's
  signature.
- The '**application/json**' is not supported, because, **by default**,
  the Spring cannot find a **proper HttpMessageConverter** to do the **converting job**, which is step ②.

**Solution**:

- We **manually** add a proper **HttpMessageConverter** into the
  **Spring's configuration** of **our application**.

Steps:

1. Choose the **HttpMessageConverter's class** we want to use. For Json, we
   can choose from
   "org.springframework.http.converter.json.**JsonbHttpMessageConverter**",
   "org.springframework.http.converter.json.**MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter**",
   and **so on**.
2. Add the **JsonbHttpMessageConverter object** (or other kinds of Json
   HttpMessageConverter **object**) to **Spring's configuration**, by calling
   the "public void
   **configureMessageConverters**(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>>
   converters)" method of the **"WebMvcConfigurer" implementation class**
   in our application. Inside the method, we can **add any
   HttpMessageConverter object** as needed, by using "**converters.add()**".
3. Add **correspond dependency** into "pom.xml" file. For example, if you
   use the "**JsonbHttpMessageConverter**", then you need to add the
   dependencies of "**javax.json.bind-api**" and "**yasson**".

Answer (score -2):

I had same issue. finally i resolved it. Actual error was in `jackson` lib. Here is the location and code snippet.

```
/* \.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.6.5\jackson-databind-2.6.5-sources.jar!\com\fasterxml\jackson\databind\DeserializationContext.java  406 */


public boolean hasValueDeserializerFor(JavaType type, AtomicReference<Throwable> cause) {
        try {
            return _cache.hasValueDeserializerFor(this, _factory, type);
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            if (cause != null) {
                cause.set(e);
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            if (cause == null) { // earlier behavior
                throw e;
            }
            cause.set(e);
        }
        return false;
    }
```